# Pay with Bitcoin?

Tags: payment, php, websites

I want to add Bitcoin payments on my website. I've found some PHP library, but as far as I understand it's using only one wallet for incoming payments, and possibly just tracking for confirmations. Is that how all of the payment gateways work? If that's the case, how does it recognize which payment is from whom? For example, if two customers buy the same thing on the same time, and only one pays for it, how would it know which one paid? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> how it recognizes which payment is from whom?

I believe you need a system, based on an HD wallet, that generates a new receive address for every order and keeps track of which receive addresses were assigned to each order number and customer ID (or other unique identifiers)